# Parametrization of a curve in 3d.

Tags: calculus

I have two equations, $x^2+y^2=25$ & $z=(1/\pi)*(\arctan(x/y))$.
I got $x=5\cos t$, $y=5\sin t$. I subbed $x$ and $y$ into $z$ but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

Note that $x/y=\cot(t)$ and that

$$\arctan(\cot(t))=\pi/2 -t$$

Comment: I don't think I get this...

Comment: @deanaf What is it that you don't understand?  Draw a right triangle and ask "what is the arctangent of the cotangent of one of the acute angles?"

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Only a small step next.

$$ (x,y,z)= 5( \cos (t), \sin (t) ,\, \frac12 - t / \pi) $$

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but where did the arctan go?

Comment: compensating functions arctan and tan disappear

Comment: It's $\arctan(\cot(t))$, not $\arctan(\tan(t))$.

Comment: I am sorry .. that was a typo.